# How split a string using regex pattern

Tags: java, android, regex

How split  a [0] like words from string using regex pattern.0 can replace any integer number.
I used regex pattern,

```
private static final String REGEX = "[\\d]";
```

But it returns string with [.

**Spliting Code**

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile(REGEX);
String items[] = p.split(lure_value_save[0]);
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @JavaDevil i am using Pattern p=Pattern.compile(REGEX);   String items[]=p.split(lure_value_save[0]);

Comment: Do a match, not a split

Comment: Why not splitting by comma? `List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));`

Comment: @RogerRapid Sorry.here is little problem.String either contain [0] or [1].etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the brackets:

```
String REGEX = "\\[\\d+\\]";
```

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't offer an elegant solution to extract the numbers. This is the way to go:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);

String test = "[0],[1],[2]";
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);

List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();     
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group());
}
```